# Default Shopify CSS seems busted, can't edit site. Attached image

Tags: shopify

Out of the blue, EVERY browser shows the same problem. The left-most column is squashed and refuses to expand.  It makes it impossible to edit the template options. Any ideas?  thanks :-)

[image]

Comment: This looks like a glitch with Shopify and would be better addressed by opening up a support ticket with their support team

Comment: Note: If you shrink your screen width to 599px wide or less, the sidebar should expand to be 100% of the window width - this might help if you're in a pinch and need to make updates right now

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It only happens in Chrome, so doing edits in Safari. Works fine there. I was looking for a way to mark your answer as "solved", but have been off SO for a year. Ok, will dive back and update that tomorrow.

Comment: I'll turn my comments into an answer for you then, if they helped :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a glitch with Shopify and would be better addressed by opening up a support ticket with their support team

Note: If you shrink your screen width to 599px wide or less, the sidebar should expand to be 100% of the window width - this might help if you're in a pinch and need to make updates right now